# execute stored procedure with a loop and combine results

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, union

I have a stored procedure in SQL server 2008.

This stored procedure (lets call it sp1), accepts ID (string),FromDate,ToDate and returns col1,col2,col3

I tried to alter sp1 to accept IDList (ID1,ID2,...,IDn), but it is way over my head.

I need help with creating a new SP (lets call it SP2) that accepts IDList,FromDate,ToDate , and then loops with the id list and calls SP1 and union the results.

I hope I am clear...

This is the original SP, If you can make it accept UnitIMEIList it will also be great:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetGeneratorsReport]
@UnitIMEI varchar(15),
@DateFrom [datetime],
@DateTo [datetime]
AS
BEGIN
-- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
-- interfering with SELECT statements.
SET NOCOUNT ON;

DECLARE @mycur CURSOR
DECLARE @GeneratorId int
DECLARE @FieldId int
DECLARE @SensorName nvarchar(50)
DECLARE @StateNO bit
DECLARE @ReadingDate [datetime]
DECLARE @Value bit
DECLARE @FirstRun bit 
DECLARE @SDate [datetime]
DECLARE @UnitName nvarchar(50)

--SET @UnitIMEI='358484004085845'
SET @UnitName = (SELECT TOP 1 NickName FROM Vehicles WHERE UnitIEMI = @UnitIMEI)

IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM tempdb.dbo.sysobjects WHERE ID = OBJECT_ID(N'tempdb..#GeneratorsTempTable')) BEGIN DROP TABLE #GeneratorsTempTable END
    CREATE TABLE #GeneratorsTempTable (
        SensorId int,
        UnitIMEI varchar(15),
        UnitName nvarchar(50),
        SensorName nvarchar(50),
        FromDate [datetime],
        ToDate [datetime]
    )

SET @mycur = CURSOR
FOR
SELECT 104+[GPIO], [Name], [StateNO]
FROM [VehicleTrack].[dbo].[UnitSensors] 
WHERE [UnitIMEI]=@UnitIMEI AND Type=3

OPEN @mycur

FETCH NEXT FROM @mycur INTO @FieldId, @SensorName, @StateNO

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN
        SET @FirstRun = 1
        SET @SDate = NULL
        DECLARE messageCur CURSOR 
        FOR 
        SELECT     ProtocolMessages.Date, convert(bit, AdditionalReadings.Value) AS Value
        FROM         ProtocolMessages INNER JOIN
                              AdditionalReadings ON ProtocolMessages.Id = AdditionalReadings.MessageId
        WHERE     (ProtocolMessages.UnitIEMI = @UnitIMEI) AND AdditionalReadings.FieldId = @FieldId AND ProtocolMessages.Date >= @DateFrom AND ProtocolMessages.Date <= @DateTo
        ORDER BY ProtocolMessages.Date
        OPEN messageCur
        FETCH NEXT FROM messageCur INTO @ReadingDate, @Value
        WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
            BEGIN
                IF (@Value > 1)
                    SET @Value = @Value - 2
                IF (@FirstRun = 1 AND @SDate IS NULL)
                BEGIN -- the first run
                    SET @FirstRun = 0 -- flip the bit for all future runs
                    IF (@Value = @StateNO)
                        SET @SDate = @ReadingDate
                END
                ELSE -- all subsequent runs after the first 
                BEGIN    
                    IF (@SDate IS NULL)
                    BEGIN
                        IF (@Value = @StateNO)
                            SET @SDate = @ReadingDate
                    END
                    ELSE 
                    BEGIN  
                        IF (@Value <> @StateNO)
                        BEGIN
                            -- Store
                            INSERT INTO #GeneratorsTempTable ([SensorId], [UnitIMEI], [UnitName], [SensorName] , [FromDate], [ToDate]) VALUES (@FieldId - 104, @UnitIMEI, @UnitName, @SensorName, @SDate, @ReadingDate)
                            SET @SDate = NULL
                        END
                    END
                END
                FETCH NEXT FROM messageCur INTO @ReadingDate, @Value
            END
        CLOSE messageCur
        DEALLOCATE messageCur

        IF (@Value = @StateNO)
        BEGIN
            INSERT INTO #GeneratorsTempTable ([SensorId], [UnitIMEI], [UnitName], [SensorName] , [FromDate], [ToDate]) VALUES (@FieldId - 104, @UnitIMEI, @UnitName, @SensorName, @SDate, GETUTCDATE())
        END

        FETCH NEXT FROM @mycur INTO @FieldId, @SensorName, @StateNO
    END
DEALLOCATE @mycur
SELECT * FROM #GeneratorsTempTable
```

END

GO

Thanks

Comment: the code of the original sp ? is it relevant ? I need to create a new sp .
Can you please help me and alter the original SP to accept ID list ?

Comment: loops are procedural way of implementation. if the same can be accomplished using a set based implementation it will be faster, hence we need to see the original sp and what it does

Comment: Rather than saying "it needs to loop" you would be much better off to state the business requirement.  It's very likely that there's a more elegant and efficient solution without looping, or cursors, but no one will be able to tell you unless they can understand what data you want.

Answer (score -1):

For the benefit of other google users :)

I did it all by myself !

I created a database named 'SandBox' for that.

Create a sample table :

```
USE [SandBox]
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tblStudentGrades](
[StudentGradeID] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[StudentID] [bigint] NOT NULL,
[TestID] [bigint] NOT NULL,
[TestDate] [date] NOT NULL,
[TestGrade] [int] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
```

Put some data (If you are lazy:) ) :

```
USE [SandBox]
GO

SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[tblStudentGrades] ON
INSERT [dbo].[tblStudentGrades] ([StudentGradeID], [StudentID], [TestID],     [TestDate], [TestGrade]) VALUES (1, 1, 1, CAST(0x6E390B00 AS Date), 60)
INSERT [dbo].[tblStudentGrades] ([StudentGradeID], [StudentID], [TestID], [TestDate], [TestGrade]) VALUES (2, 1, 2, CAST(0x70390B00 AS Date), 80)
INSERT [dbo].[tblStudentGrades] ([StudentGradeID], [StudentID], [TestID], [TestDate], [TestGrade]) VALUES (3, 2, 1, CAST(0x6E390B00 AS Date), 90)
INSERT [dbo].[tblStudentGrades] ([StudentGradeID], [StudentID], [TestID], [TestDate], [TestGrade]) VALUES (4, 2, 2, CAST(0x70390B00 AS Date), 100)
INSERT [dbo].[tblStudentGrades] ([StudentGradeID], [StudentID], [TestID], [TestDate], [TestGrade]) VALUES (5, 3, 1, CAST(0x6E390B00 AS Date), 95)
INSERT [dbo].[tblStudentGrades] ([StudentGradeID], [StudentID], [TestID], [TestDate], [TestGrade]) VALUES (6, 3, 2, CAST(0x0F230100 AS Date), 98)
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[tblStudentGrades] OFF
```

Create the SP that accepts a single id:
* This is just a sample ... don't forget it - I know I can send multiple IDs as a parameter...

```
USE [SandBox]
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[spGetStudentGrades]
@StudentID bigint

AS
BEGIN
   SELECT * FROM [SandBox].[dbo].[tblStudentGrades]
   WHERE StudentID = @StudentID;
END

GO
```

Now for the new SP that will allow multiple execution of the above SP (exactly what I was looking for):

```
USE [SandBox]
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO


CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[spGetMultiple]
@StudentIDList varchar(100)

AS
BEGIN

   DECLARE @StudentID VARCHAR(10)

   --------------------------------------------------
   -- Create a temporary table to hold the results:
   --------------------------------------------------
    IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM tempdb.dbo.sysobjects WHERE ID =   OBJECT_ID(N'tempdb..#tblTemporaryGrades')) BEGIN DROP TABLE #tblTemporaryGrades    END
        CREATE TABLE #tblTemporaryGrades (
        StudentGradeID bigint,
        StudentID bigint,
        TestID bigint, 
        TestDate date, 
        TestGrade int
    )
   --------------------------------------------------
   -- Add a comma to the end of the ID list, 
   -- so the last ID will be also included.
   SET @StudentIDList = @StudentIDList + ',' ;   
   ---------------------------------------------------

   WHILE CHARINDEX(',', @StudentIDList) > 0 
   BEGIN

      -- STEP 1 :
      -- Extract the current StudentID we want to get from the original SP
      SET @StudentID = SUBSTRING(@StudentIDList, 1, ( CHARINDEX(',',   @StudentIDList) - 1 ))            
      PRINT '@StudentID = ' + @StudentID;

      -- STEP 2 :
      -- Gather the data using the original SP

      INSERT INTO #tblTemporaryGrades EXEC spGetStudentGrades @StudentID


  -- STEP 3 :
  -- Update the student ID to exclude the last StudentID we worked with      
  SET @StudentIDList = SUBSTRING(@StudentIDList, CHARINDEX(',', @StudentIDList) + 1, LEN(@StudentIDList))

      PRINT 'NEW @StudentIDList = ' + @StudentIDList;
   END

   SELECT * FROM #tblTemporaryGrades
END

GO
```

Feel like testing it ?
Go ahead:

```
USE [SandBox]
GO

DECLARE @return_value int

EXEC    @return_value = [dbo].[spGetMultiple]
    @StudentIDList = N'3,2,1'

SELECT  'Return Value' = @return_value

GO
```

Good luck all !